# How does Lt. Col. William Cage get this suit?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

The first few times cage meets Sergeant Rita Rose Vrataski in the battle field he just has *normal* everyday exoskeleton suit:

[image]

The suit with out a person in it.
[image]

But then, in the scenes after he meets Sergeant Vrataski he has these special guns that fire from his back pack,

[image]

The suit from side on clearly showing the guns,

No. 1

[image]

No. 2

[image]

An image clearly showing no guns,

[image]

Taking into account that he always is taken into combat by the ship that Master Sergeant Farell commands, and they fit him with a suit, how did he get this special suit?

Comment: As far as I can tell he always had them (folded into the backpack of his suit). It wasn't until he learned how to control them that he started using them.

Comment: @Valorum, they are not there , see the first image of the suit.

Comment: I don't see a rear image. Are you sure he's not just blocking them from view?

Comment: Was there also not a scene where he "talks soldier" with the crewman and convinces him to turn on his guns?

Comment: @Valorum, added a pic to show standard suit.

Comment: @KyloRen great question! However, I thought his rank was Major, not Lt. Colonel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the scene before, Rita and Cage are continually getting nailed by a mimic. Their attempts to divert around it, duck it and kill it with handguns fail over and over again. Rita (who seems trigger-happy at the best of times) presumably suggested that the problem is that they're under-gunned. In the very next scene, Rita and Cage both have **lots and lots more weaponry** than before.

[image]

### How did he get them?

He probably convinced the same soldier who unlocked his guns that he needs *[something a little bigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16SIvVKtuks)* to be added to his suit than the standard loadout. Either that or he just picked them off a dead grunt on the beach.

### How did he mount them to his suit?

We can assume that these guns are not standard-issue, but *do* attach to a standard suit. Since they seem [next to impossible to self-mount](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QRpJv1nYG4), they might have been attached by the soldier in the transport or, failing that, by Rita on the beach.

Comment: @KyloRen - I've explained why they felt that he needed them, and added some supposition that they were either taken from a dead grunt or simply added by the soldier in the transport. I highly doubt you're going to get anything more detailed (or explicative) than that.

Comment: Good answer. I'm taken back to one part of the movie after Cage had done 'several' repeats & gotten used to the gear, that he is not so much asking, but indeed specifying, what extra ammo. he needs. The soldier he spoke to just took one look into his eyes, then gave him what he needed.

Comment: OK, I see what you did.

Answer (score 5):

I've watched the movie recently and I believe you're overthinking this.

First "time", Cage is deployed on the beach with J-squad. These are regular soldiers, with standard-edition exoskeletons with no extra weapons:

[image: without weaopns]

In the same battle, Rita Vrataski is deployed in her own elite squad. These are some kind of black ops special forces, they have badass black exoskeletons and most of them are wearing masks (in order to not distract an audience from the leads):

[image: Special forces]

And their suits are equipped with extra weapons:

[image: Rita Vrataski]

After Cage meets Rita Vrataski he doesn't return to Sergeant Farrell and J-Squad. For the rest of the movie, he is mostly deployed with her elite division and gets to wear their cool suit.

There is an exception: once in a movie Cage gets disillusioned and decides not to involve Rita Vrataski and go to Omega all by himself. To do this he returns to J-Squad. In this time loop, he specifically asks another soldier to get him extra ammunition.